# Detect when page is being refreshed over and over in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a large C# .net project that I recently optimized and it's working great. It's a pretty big code library though so I am not familiar with it in great detail.

That said, everything works very well until once in a while a user will get frustrated that a page takes a few seconds to load and starts refreshing a page over and over. Looking at my active processes in IIS, one user had refreshed the same page 300 times in about as many seconds (so non stop refreshing for 5 minutes)

Since this page was already somewhat slower this brought the server to its knees. 100% CPU for about an hour until I recycled the process and then killed the old w3wp. Immediately everything came back to life and everything is fast again.

Is there any way to detect this behavior (ie, page is already being loaded by this user/session) and instead of a full refresh just piggy-back on the already running thread, or canceling the first thread, or really any sort of mitigation to catch this?

Comment: How long does the page take to load on average? (in seconds) Out of curiosity.

Comment: @alans About a second usually, but occasionally as much as 5 seconds.

Comment: Do you already have output caching enabled on IIS?

Comment: @alans No. That sounds promising though! Looking into that now

Comment: You're not going to be happy with this, but your page is too slow. The solution to users hitting "refresh" is to make the page faster, not disable the refresh. That said, you can return a "server busy" page when the load gets above a certain percentage. The users will slow down on the F5 key if all they're getting is a boring static page.

Comment: I still need the site to not go down if a page is refreshed over and over. Even it loads in 100ms the ability for someone to knock out the site this way isn't good

Comment: But yeah, I already optimized it from 30-60 seconds down to 1-5. Limited by the client's budget on how much time I can work on that. They are pretty happy with it except when this occasionally happens. And they would be happy to keep paying me to just restart the process once in a while, but I don't want to do that.

Comment: It is one page where this happens? You cannot reproduce this for other (slow) pages?

Comment: It's pretty hard to reproduce really. You have to use a user with a lot of data in their account, go to that one page and refresh it many times quickly enough before the results are cached.

Comment: @JeffDavis  "I still need the site to not go down if a page is refreshed over and over." You'll still need to be able to handle overload conditions. Handing out "server busy" pages means some users get data and some don't, while trying to service **all** the requests means nobody gets data. Some services allow rate limiting, so you can ignore requests that come in faster than "X"

Comment: @Terry Yeah, rate limits + an output caching strategy looks like exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: FWIW, if you want to know about high load conditions, check out reddit's strategies They're actually documented somewhere and work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very simple solution would be to set a session variable (for instance the time the page is requested). Then on every request to that page, you know both that the page has been requested before and when, so you can choose to break.

Comment: This is pretty going to be the slightly more medium-term solution for the page. (Short term being the tweaks above and long-term being more optimization)